Buscar nombre dentro de un campo varchar PostgreSQL
Necesito solución para este tema:
Necesito encontrar/filtrar a través de un campo varchar, el nombre homologado del mismo.
Por ejemplo, tengo el campo nomb_a (que la data es insertada por el cliente, con lo cual ya sabemos que hay errores y excepciones a full).
Entonces, tenemos, para el campo 'nomb_a' los siguientes datos:
GAJO AR GAJOAR GAJOARSGC-234
Para los 3 casos necesito que devuelva para el campo nombre homologado: GAJO AR
Les dejo más ejemplos:
ROPE CR ROPECR1 ROPECR ROPECRSGC-937
Para los 4 casos necesito que devuelva para el campo nombre homologado: ROPE CR
Un dato importante, es que analizando la base, veo que se repite el nombre_aSGC- .. Para estos casos también se podría tomar en cuenta que devuelva todo lo anterior a SGC- (es solo una idea que se me ocurre)
También el campo nombre homologado se ha estado actualizando manualmente por algunos meses, así que ya hay algunos nombres homologados que se podrían tomar en cuenta.
Si necesitan algún otro dato adicional, estoy al pendiente.
Tengo entendido que creando una función podría hacerlo, pero soy nueva con Postgresql. ¿Me dan una mano? Gracias.

¡Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos/trabajos. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o haz una pregunta específica sobre un error o problema que tienes para implementar TU solución a la tarea/proyecto.
